# How to expand/shrink glcanvas (Jogl) if the user resizes the frame?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, glcanvas

I have a glcanvas inside a jpanel with a BorderLayout. The size of the canvas should be dependent on the window size.
The initial size is set via

```
glCanvas.setSize(640, 480);
```

And it is added to the panel like this

```
jPanel3DModel.add(Model3DCanvas.getInstance().getCanvas());
jPanelRight.add(jPanel3DModel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

However the size of the canvas is fixed and all the panels of the other components in my frame just resize.

Comment: BorderLayout.NORTH doesn't resize. Only BorderLayout.CENTER gets resized. You should use the GLJPanel, as the wiki suggests: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing#JOGL_in_Swing_using_the_GLJPanel

Comment: Ok I put the canvas into the CENTER. The Panel resizes but not the canvas.

Comment: What you haven't explained is the ``jPanel3DModel`` component. Because you don't add the canvas directly to the ``jPanelRight``. Therefore the resizing is dependent on the resizing behavior of the ``jPanel3DModel`` component.

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to react to the `JPanel` resize "manually", you can use a `ComponentListener` as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html

Assuming `canvas` is your GLCanvas and `jpanel` the component your canvas resizing is depending on.

```java
jPanel.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
  public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent event) {
    int width=event.getComponent().getWidth();
    int height=event.getComponent().getHeight();
    canvas.setSize(width,height);
  }
});
```